# What are advantages of enh-ruby-mode vs ruby-mode

Tags: ruby, emacs

Some prepackaged emacs distributions use `enh-ruby-mode` instead of default `ruby-mode` (e.g. [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs))

What are the advantages of `enh-ruby-mode` compared to `ruby-mode` in terms of features it provides?

Answer (score 1):

[From its GitHub README](https://github.com/zenspider/enhanced-ruby-mode#description):

> ### Description
>
> Enhanced Ruby Mode replaces the emacs ruby mode that comes with ruby.
>
> It uses the Ripper class found in ruby 1.9.2 (and later) to parse and indent the source code. As a consquence only ruby 1.9.2 (or later) syntax is parsed correctly.
>
> Syntax checking is also performed.

The built-in `ruby-mode`, like most built-in modes, [uses regular expressions to parse source files](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/progmodes/ruby-mode.el?id=emacs-24.5#n47). `enh-ruby-mode` uses [Ruby's `Ripper` class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html), giving it better semantics. Syntax checking also appears to be something that `ruby-mode` doesn't provide.

Comment: Lack of info in README is the reason why I asked the question - it only states that it replaces `ruby-mode`, it does not provide information on what additional features it provides or what issues of `ruby-mode` it solves...

Comment: @jesenko, the README *does* say what additional features `enh-ruby-mode` provides, though it doesn't specifically dig into `ruby-mode` features. Please see my updated answer.